# issues with file uploading with ionic4 App

Tags: angular, cordova-plugins, ionic4

i am using the tutorial
The Ionic 4 Images Guide (Capture, Store & Upload with POST).

https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-image-upload-storage/

I have most things working except for the readFile Method.

```
readFile(file: any) {
  console.log ("readFile", file); // [log] - readFile
  const reader = new FileReader();
  console.log ("reader", reader); // [log] - reader
  reader.onloadend = () => {
    console.log ("reader progress");  // do not see in xcode
    const formData = new FormData();
    console.log ("formData", formData);  // do not see in xcode
    const imgBlob = new Blob([reader.result], {
        type: file.type
    });
    formData.append('file', imgBlob, file.name);
    this.uploadImageData(formData);
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file); 
  console.log ("readAsArrayBuffer", file);  // [log] - readAsArrayBuffer
}
```

at the reader.onloadend line 5 it seems to stop working.  the console.logs do not show in Xcode. or Android Studio.  I have build this test version to match exactly the tutorial.

As a note I am using "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2".  Would  this break reader.onloadend?

Below are my console.logs

```
[log] - readFile {"name":"1569941078510.jpg","localURL":"cdvfile://localhost/library-nosync/1569941078510.jpg",
"type":"image/jpeg","lastModified":1569941078490.799,
"lastModifiedDate":1569941078490.799,"size":6673995,"start":0,"end":6673995}


[log] - reader {"__zone_symbol__originalInstance":
{"_readyState":0,"_error":null,"_result":null,"_progress":null,"_localURL":"","_realReader":{}}}

[log] - readAsArrayBuffer {"name":"1569941078510.jpg","localURL":"cdvfile://localhost/library-nosync/1569941078510.jpg",
"type":"image/jpeg","lastModified":1569941078490.799,"lastModifiedDate":1569941078490.799,"size":6673995,"start":0,"end":6673995}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is I was using a ionic capacitor app with some cordova plugin added.  One I build a ionic/cordova app all worked fine.  It appears ionic/capacitor can interfere with cordova plugins.